# How to put KerasClassifier, Hyperopt and Sklearn cross-validation together

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperopt

I am performing a hyperparameter tuning optimization (hyperopt) tasks with sklearn on a Keras models. I am trying to optimize KerasClassifiers using the Sklearn cross-validation, Some code follows:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        Dense(output_dim=params['units1'],
              input_dim=features_.shape[1],
              kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(Activation(params['activation']))
    model.add(Dropout(params['dropout1']))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    ...
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Now what I want to do is to pass the Hyperopt params to KerasClassifier using the following way

```
def objective(params, n_folds=N_FOLDS):
    """Objective function for Hyperparameter Optimization"""

    # Keep track of evals
    global ITERATION

    ITERATION += 1

    clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,**params)

    start = timer()

    # Perform n_folds cross validation
    cv_results = cross_val_score(clf,
                                 features_,
                                 labels,
                                 cv=5
                                 ).mean()

    run_time = timer() - start

    # Loss must be minimized
    loss = -cv_results

    # Dictionary with information for evaluation
    return {
        'loss': loss,
        'params': params,
        'iteration': ITERATION,
        'train_time': run_time,
        'status': STATUS_OK
    }
```

I define the search space as:

```
space = {'units1': hp.choice('units1', [64, 128, 256, 512]),
    'units2': hp.choice('units2', [64, 128, 256, 512]),
    'dropout1': hp.choice('dropout1', [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]),
    'dropout2': hp.choice('dropout2', [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]),
    'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]),
    'nb_epochs': hp.choice('nb_epochs', [10, 50, 100]),
    'optimizer': opt_search_space,
    'activation': 'relu' }
```

Run optimization

```
best = fmin(fn = objective, space = space, algo = tpe.suggest, 
            max_evals = MAX_EVALS, trials = bayes_trials, rstate = np.random.RandomState(50))
```

But it fails giving this error:

> ValueError: activation is not a legal parameter

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the hyper parameter as the input parameters for `create_model` function. Then you can feed `params` dict. Also change the key `nb_epochs` into `epochs` in the search space. Read more about the other valid parameter [here](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/).

Try the following simplified example of your's.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

import time

def timer():
   now = time.localtime(time.time())
   return now[5]


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2,
                           n_informative=4, weights=[0.7, 0.3],
                           random_state=0)
```

Defining `keras` model:

```
def create_model(units1, activation, dropout):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units1,
                    input_dim=X.shape[1],
                    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                    activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

```
def objective(params, n_folds=2):
    """Objective function for Hyperparameter Optimization"""

    # Keep track of evals
    global ITERATION

    ITERATION += 1

    clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,**params)

    start = timer()

    # Perform n_folds cross validation
    cv_results = cross_val_score(clf, X, y,
                                 cv=5, 
                                 ).mean()

    run_time = timer() - start

    # Loss must be minimized
    loss = -cv_results

    # Dictionary with information for evaluation
    return {
        'loss': loss,
        'params': params,
        'iteration': ITERATION,
        'train_time': run_time,
        'status': STATUS_OK
    }

from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, Trials, STATUS_OK

space = {'units1': hp.choice('units1', [12, 64]),
         'dropout': hp.choice('dropout1', [0.25, 0.5]),
         'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [10, 20]),
         'epochs': hp.choice('nb_epochs', [2, 3]),
         'activation': 'relu'
        }
```

```
global ITERATION
ITERATION = 0

bayes_trials = Trials()

best = fmin(fn = objective, space = space, algo = tpe.suggest, 
            max_evals = 5, trials = bayes_trials, rstate = np.random.RandomState(50))
```

Comment: Thanks foe your answer, please have a look at my further questions below

Comment: Glad that it helps! Please ask a new question, when you have one. Dont post a question as a answer.

Comment: I ask my new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855499/how-can-i-pass-the-hyperopt-params-to-kerasclassifier-if-i-set-conditional-searc), please have a look, thanks.